# Where would I add this jQuery code to in my page for a form?

Tags: jquery, html, input

This jquery code below is for a text input box to help users enter times in a formatted way.

I have tested it on here

http://jsfiddle.net/nNpjm/2/

I am now wanting to include it in my html form now however I do not know where it would go?

Should it go in the onchange tag?

```
input.click(function() {

        $(this).prop({
            selectionStart: 0, //moves cursor to poition zero in input box
            selectionEnd: 0
        });

    }).keydown(function() {

        var sel = $(this).prop('selectionStart'),
            val = $(this).val(),
            newsel = sel === 2 ? 3: sel;
            newsel = sel === 5 ? 6: newsel;

        $(this).val(val.substring(0, newsel) + val.substring(newsel + 1))

        .prop({
            selectionStart: newsel,
            selectionEnd: newsel
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ball rolling you can simply place the javascript below your form on the same page. You'll eventually want to place all your javascript in external `.js` files and include them via `<script src="my_javascript_file.js"></script>`

I've included your script below. You'll notice that [it's wrapped in CDATA tags](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) - this is a fail-safe to handle an XHTML doctype so that the XML parser ignores the script completely and does not fail when it encounters unfamiliar characters:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="whatever.html">
    <!-- additional fields, submit button, etc -->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var input = $("<input>", { //this bit will be removed in the form
        name: 'time',
        val: '00:00:00',
        maxlength: '8',
        size: '5'
    });

    input.click(function() {

        $(this).prop({
            selectionStart: 0,
            selectionEnd: 0
        });

    }).keydown(function() {

        var sel = $(this).prop('selectionStart'),
            val = $(this).val(),
            newsel = sel === 2 ? 3: sel;
            newsel = sel === 5 ? 6: newsel;

        $(this).val(val.substring(0, newsel) + val.substring(newsel + 1))

        .prop({
            selectionStart: newsel,
            selectionEnd: newsel
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $('#form').append(input);
    });

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but im using php to make my form, I just want the script to interact with my php generated input fields made by codeigniter php.

Thanks

Comment: You'd just stick this code in your view, and replace the `<form..>` html with whatever variable you assign in your controller to contain the form. As long as the form has the `id="form"` then you can use `$('#form').append(input);`. Just replace `#form` with whatever the id of the form is if you decide on another one.

Answer (score 1):

Embed your code inside a `script` tag, and change the first line to:

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputId').click(...
});
```

Comment: -1 if you look at his fiddle he's referencing `input` as a variable as he is creating the element on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the documents load function like this:

```
$(document).load(function(){      
    var input = $("<input>", { //this bit will be removed in the form        
        name: 'time',        
        val: '00:00:00',        
        maxlength: '8',        
        size: '5'    
    });    
    input.click(function() {        
        $(this).prop({            
            selectionStart: 0,            
            selectionEnd: 0        
        });    
    }).keydown(function() {        
        var sel = $(this).prop('selectionStart'),            
        val = $(this).val(),            
        newsel = sel === 2 ? 3: sel;            
        newsel = sel === 5 ? 6: newsel;        
        $(this).val(val.substring(0, newsel) + val.substring(newsel + 1)).prop({            
            selectionStart: newsel,            
            selectionEnd: newsel        
        });    
    });    
    $('body').append(input);  
});
```